# Same method but different signature depending on .NET framework version?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, uwp

Urgh sorry for the bad title, really didn't know what would be correct (please change if you see something more fitting).

I have a DLL file which I use for a project based on `WinRT` (or rather I use it when I build a `Universal Windows 10` app) and I also use it for a "normal" desktop application. But my problem is that I use `System.Activator.CreateInstance<T>(typeof(T), true)` to be able to create some classes with a private constructor. This works on the desktop application. But on WinRT the method `CreateInstance<T>(...)` doesn't take the same parameters. What's the best approach to solve this?

Can I check during runtime if I'm on WinRT or if it's a "normal" application? And based on that use appropriate signature?

(Sorry if I'm using the the word WinRT wrong etc, I'm having a hard to grasping what is what with all these universal app terms flying around)

Comment: Why do you think it has a different signature? (I'm no expert in WinRT, but that seems unusual.)

Comment: I know for a fact it has different signature. Because I have one WinRT project open and there is only 3 signatures available. While the one for desktop has 13. I also saw a comment a few weeks ago (by coincidence) that one should note that, that is the case (can't find it again though). :)

Comment: I think this overload isn't supported in WinRT. You can call `CreateInstance(Type)` but `CreateInstance(Type, bool)` is not available, probably due to sandboxed security constraints.

Comment: Yes Sean I think that's what I said in my post. But what can I do to work-around it? Are you saying that my only option is to only use the CreateInstance(Type)?

Comment: @user2422321 - You're out of luck as the `CreateInstance(Type)` method wants a public constructor. You should probably explore why you need to create a copy of a class with a private constructor in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Sean, if that is indeed the only solution, you should post it as an answer. I was more interesting if there was a possible work-around (like the one i mentioned in my post).

Comment: If you want to call a different method based on what runtime you're compiled for, you can use [preprocessor directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx), although this won't help you instantiate using private constructors on WinRT. You will need to find another way to do that, but you can at least use the simpler method on non-RT runtimes,

Comment: @christophano does this require me to do anything special when building my DLL (like changing project settings for the DLL)? Or it just as simple as typing something like #if WINRT do this #elif do this instead #endif?

Comment: @user2422321 you will need to set the flag in the appropriate project settings. Typically, if I'm building against multiple frameworks I'll have multiple project files referencing the same source code.
Each project file will set the relevant preprocessor flag (build tab in project settings) then I can use different code for different runtimes, if necessary.
Check out [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) to see how they reference the same source from multiple projects and use preprocessor directives in the source file.

Comment: @christophano Thank you for the explanation. I think I will stick to use the "only-public constructor"-way, so that I don't need different DLLs. This is the _only_ place I need to make this change and feel it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CreateInstance(Type, bool)` overload isn't available in WinRT due to sandboxed security constraints, which only leaves you with the `CreateInstance(Type)` overload. However, this won't allow you to create an instance of a class that has a private constructor.

You should probably explore why you need to create a copy of a class with a private constructor in the first place. The author of the class didn't intend for it to be used by a third party, so creating an instance is risky. If the class has a protected constructor then you can always derive from the class and give your new class a public constructor. If it's private then you are out of luck! One option might be to contact the author of the class and ask them to make it public, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Sean. I'm actually the author of the classes with private constructors and wanted to prevent creation of them. They are private because they are used in a generic Singleton/Factory-way. :)